# Single Engine operation on Twin Engine aircraft

Tags: jet-engine, airliner, aircraft-physics

I recently came across ETOPS and I wanted to know:

How does a twin-engined aircraft  balance out the lack of thrust on one side in the event that one of the engines is non operational? Any information is appreciated.

Apologies if this has been asked before or if it doesn't comply with other standards. I'm new around here and couldn't quite find anything that addresses what I wanted to know. If someone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17256/what-would-happen-if-one-of-the-engines-failed-during-takeoff-and-other-engine-i

Comment: @jamiec that helps a lot lot. thanks.